# What's Madara's Mangekyou Sharingan special ability?

Tags: naruto

Obito can use Kamui, Shin can manipulate and control weapons, Itachi can use Amaterasu, and Shisui can cast powerful genjutsu. But I don't understand what the special ability Madara got from his Mangekyou Sharingan.

I don't think Susanoo and controlling Nine Tails are special abilities because they are basic abilities of MS. So what's the special ability of Madara's MS?

Comment: This was the most detailed opinion I came across => https://qr.ae/prCdlC
Although, the show never stated explicitly about Madara's MS special ability ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://gamerant.com/naruto-madaras-ems-abilities-explained/#:%7E:text=One%20such%20element%20was%20Madara%27s,of%20his%20Eternal%20Mangekyo%20Sharingan.):

> One such element was Madara’s EMS ability – the power to reverse time.
>
> The animation showed Madara’s EMS spinning uncontrollably, resulting in everything moving backwards. This was revealed to be time reversal, a direct ability of his Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan. However, this technique is technically non-canon since it was only witnessed in an OVA, meaning it's not enough to cement this jutsu as one of Madara’s actual EMS powers.

Comment: Unsure of the extent to which this answers the question, given that - by its own admission - its canonicity is questionable. Also, please be aware that if you're answering a question using a quotation from elsewhere, you need to clearly indicate that the quote is a quote and make it clear where you got it from.

Answer (score -1):

According to [the wiki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan#Madara_Uchiha), his eyes abilities haven't been explicitly shown.
Also, is hard to say that Shin's Mangekyou *specifically* had that telekinesis ability, because in his arc there are multiple different eyes and creatures that show the same ability.